# vue js - image is not showing on production

Tags: vue.js

When I test locally, there is no problem; the image is showing. But when I build the app and send to the server 'dist' file, the image is not showing.

```
image: require ('./assets/vexento.jpg')
```

This is my src row. In the local, its working. So there is no problem on this row.

Note:

```
<script src="/js/app.550aebc7.js"></script>
```

In the index.html there is this src, and I changed it manually like this:

```
<script src="./js/app.550aebc7.js"></script>
```

After changing the app is working but the image file is not showing.

How to solve this problem? If you help me I will be glad.

Comment: Could you sjare a bit more of your code? It might be possible that in prod mode your setup is inlining the file so there's no real import.

Answer (score -1):

I solved. Create a "vue.config.js" file in main area and paste this code:

```js
    module.exports = {
    publicPath: ''
}
```

And problem has solved.

Comment: it crashed my production...